# Any experience with iRobot ATRV-JR?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am building a robot testbed at my community college and I inherited an iRobot ATRV-JR platform, but no documentation or other information.  Does anyone here have experience or know who I can contact.

Thanks,
Jonathan West

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174825/any-experience-with-irobot-atrv-jr?/) by [JWest](https://answers.ros.org/users/18944/jwest/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2014-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These robots have a proprietary board inside called an rFlex bus that communicates with the sensors and motors. I've been trying to communicate with the rFlex board on my ATRV-Jr for a while now with no luck so far.

I found that the Washington University robotics group has written some ROS software that communicates with rFlex based robots, but it didn't seem to work for me. But I haven't had time to troubleshoot deeply yet. It's not my main project.

http://wu-ros-pkg.sourceforge.net

Here is a manual for the iRobot/RWI software that runs on the onboard PC.  It's terribly old not supported anymore, so I did not find it useful.

[http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~shapiro/Courses/CSE716/MobilityManRev4.pdf](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/%7Eshapiro/Courses/CSE716/MobilityManRev4.pdf)

I have been able to drive mine around the lab using an old wired joystick and walking behind it.  I can talk you through that if you'd like to do that. Let me know if you're interested.

---

Originally posted by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) with karma: 486 on 2014-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0